# Как сделать, чтобы полосы прокрутки не уходили за пределы страницы?

Tags: html, css

У меня блоки не влазят на страницу...

[image: Вот так должно получиться]

```css
body {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  bottom:50px;
}
#menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  z-index: 5;
}
#data{
  width: 50%;
}
#data-content{
  padding-left:20px;
}
#container{
  /*display: flex;*/
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 100%-50px;
  /*top:50px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /*position: relative;*/*/
}
#left{
  left:0
}

#right{
  top:60px;
  right:0
}
#left, #right{
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  padding-top:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
.bottom-padding{
  height:20px;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
#left-content{
  background: red;
  width: 100%
  height: 100%;
  padding-left:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom:240px;
}
#right-content{
  background:green;
  width: 100%
  height: 100%;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="data">
  <div id="data-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero blanditiis tempora dolores facilis, nisi error laudantium explicabo sapiente non fugit iste voluptates repellat temporibus architecto a deserunt ex. Voluptatem velit perferendis eos deserunt labore saepe debitis quo incidunt. Debitis, obcaecati cum. Maxime quos quas facere, quam qui amet, impedit ratione fugit dolore ad reprehenderit pariatur aut velit cumque neque ipsam maiores. Veniam sint in voluptate cumque voluptas eveniet quod id doloremque ad placeat voluptatem omnis, magni aliquid incidunt corporis minima modi fugit delectus? Excepturi architecto ex consequatur mollitia autem quod reprehenderit cumque similique. Explicabo cum necessitatibus ab dolores harum quae.</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">

    <div id="left-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum asperiores rem, aut eaque. Ab harum iste veritatis rerum deleniti assumenda pariatur repellendus facere, ea tenetur, ullam blanditiis, nihil earum facilis laborum eligendi perferendis, autem debitis obcaecati aliquid hic doloremque asperiores! Similique porro dolorum eum. Vel blanditiis eligendi adipisci ipsum neque ea, est maxime laborum incidunt eveniet perspiciatis, placeat quod cupiditate voluptas animi ipsam aperiam velit veniam, praesentium at harum quaerat voluptatum. Perferendis natus ratione nam, dolorem velit, libero maxime non, adipisci molestias praesentium eius unde, corrupti quisquam! Quasi delectus alias, illum expedita esse. Veniam incidunt molestias culpa, libero in numquam eos. Laudantium nesciunt necessitatibus, ducimus, illum repellat dolores ut voluptatum dolore labore corrupti a adipisci corporis, reiciendis velit, facere voluptate aliquam voluptatem dignissimos dolorem atque. Animi soluta necessitatibus voluptates quasi dignissimos. Rerum cupiditate, sunt voluptas, nostrum voluptatem sit delectus eligendi natus ut, dignissimos illum dolores velit pariatur aspernatur laboriosam reiciendis odio quos. Tempora doloremque repellat est iusto ullam mollitia fuga repellendus deleniti laboriosam, accusantium, nisi, qui sapiente nesciunt, consequatur veniam suscipit harum hic magnam dolorem odio pariatur atque fugiat quae maxime! Ipsa blanditiis excepturi cumque sequi, at distinctio earum aut placeat perspiciatis quam doloribus laborum eveniet officia eos tenetur fugit assumenda repudiandae similique, dolore eligendi, iste nulla ex. Rerum accusantium similique ratione, vero eveniet sequi nisi amet blanditiis porro, corporis dolorum facilis voluptatum dignissimos optio repudiandae sint fugiat explicabo. Aliquam voluptas mollitia possimus, sint dolorum doloremque ducimus, illo sed fuga vel nihil iste id a odio voluptates ex eaque vero ratione quod unde laboriosam numquam. Magnam cupiditate sunt, eum veritatis vero aliquid esse consequuntur. Saepe dicta, laudantium dolorem quis, tempore, error ea culpa ducimus veritatis maxime numquam dolorum! Neque labore sed repellendus saepe, inventore. Rerum inventore molestias amet in quas porro tempore perspiciatis aspernatur enim. Dolorem distinctio repudiandae molestiae est autem culpa perspiciatis, alias? Quam dolor aspernatur illo, debitis dolores! Ipsa itaque, recusandae cum ad modi odit optio eaque est, consectetur eos totam incidunt nihil culpa fuga eligendi magni odio perferendis provident. Blanditiis quaerat sed incidunt consequuntur maxime. Iste nesciunt atque molestias minus dolorem eligendi sint reiciendis unde obcaecati. Provident minima eveniet excepturi facere, fugiat deserunt totam odit dicta reiciendis. Numquam fuga similique dolores, iste, laborum tenetur earum explicabo. Corporis voluptates provident, necessitatibus dicta! Aliquid necessitatibus modi nesciunt harum in ea est soluta vitae saepe facilis. Quis a rem eos ex sunt quae quam unde consectetur! Eos voluptates, quo qui. Eum libero fuga nulla dolores similique, culpa dolor ullam, numquam repellendus, quam exercitationem! Voluptates, hic suscipit dignissimos excepturi commodi. Excepturi repudiandae, similique eum quidem, molestiae vitae dolor aut. Sapiente qui doloremque fugit culpa possimus assumenda esse animi doloribus ratione, accusantium asperiores, placeat deserunt facere? Eligendi debitis tenetur ipsa et velit sequi sunt at nam veritatis molestiae dolores provident quo, reiciendis repellendus quos doloremque tempore eum ipsam facilis maxime. Tenetur delectus velit dolorem odit assumenda, voluptatum impedit soluta obcaecati exercitationem possimus dolores esse ratione, aliquam pariatur saepe deserunt dolorum perferendis iste sed architecto fugiat. Dignissimos esse eveniet eligendi ipsa, deserunt repudiandae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione sunt saepe, similique consequuntur cupiditate suscipit iure rem, vitae, ducimus, harum quam corporis porro. Culpa sint minima, illum rerum sed consequuntur vel, ut tempore tempora. Minus quam recusandae quibusdam labore vel accusamus fuga doloribus tempore, unde repellat esse cumque atque dolorem enim perspiciatis quidem dignissimos at temporibus id et, aut exercitationem, consequatur consequuntur voluptas? Esse officia, voluptatibus totam ex adipisci laboriosam facilis, commodi, nam modi ipsam explicabo doloremque illum, cupiditate perspiciatis reprehenderit dolores. Quidem vero voluptas, placeat repellendus nulla aspernatur illum modi. Soluta dolore distinctio asperiores, aliquid ut dignissimos repellat quisquam a rem. Consequatur, nulla. Itaque saepe aliquam explicabo, natus quod nam. Possimus repudiandae quaerat voluptatem! Praesentium, nobis ad, necessitatibus, eligendi voluptatem optio maxime repellendus rem quaerat, minima at eaque corporis deleniti ut alias officia! Officia cupiditate tempora quo omnis, similique facilis ipsum fuga enim officiis ad laborum dolor, reprehenderit dolorum optio vero qui harum libero molestias doloribus placeat fugit! Non veniam beatae, quos voluptatem fugit minima, aspernatur a, delectus nostrum alias tempore? Eaque, architecto nostrum deleniti sequi soluta dolorum ipsam reprehenderit in laboriosam, vero aliquid praesentium pariatur ut laborum eligendi repellendus debitis repudiandae mollitia odio repellat dolores quia tenetur eum. Vero nostrum voluptatum, laudantium tenetur provident, ipsa perspiciatis inventore deleniti quaerat tempore magni libero maxime vitae quod aspernatur velit voluptatem dolore omnis quasi sequi officia vel? Quos repellat voluptatibus doloribus dicta qui sint, similique ad ducimus laborum facere iure nemo magnam quidem sapiente eaque expedita nostrum laboriosam fuga. Quia, rerum, saepe! Doloribus animi illum quidem aperiam deleniti ea beatae accusamus, optio commodi, delectus obcaecati saepe quod repellendus corrupti laborum voluptates odio suscipit natus porro iure quo fugit repellat enim! Quidem unde fugiat, perspiciatis repellat praesentium. Quis dolor soluta tenetur dolore officia qui, quisquam. Modi repudiandae quasi culpa molestias! Repudiandae necessitatibus magni, et ut ratione, beatae temporibus sit adipisci repellat, reiciendis ad ipsa voluptatum consequuntur, enim quis hic. Quisquam earum veniam, soluta error doloremque. Reprehenderit nihil quisquam asperiores minima, necessitatibus. Repudiandae iusto earum accusantium atque accusamus incidunt asperiores optio modi sint, unde fugit qui animi, ratione inventore veritatis voluptates, ut ullam facere quia, eum vero! Deleniti vitae corporis quasi natus. Reiciendis, nulla. Eligendi aliquam repellendus facilis voluptate laborum distinctio blanditiis sequi veniam atque eum, architecto voluptatum incidunt sed, fugiat, adipisci quibusdam nihil ipsam recusandae velit ipsa, placeat deleniti impedit ducimus dolores! Aut, aliquid, deserunt. Ipsa reiciendis nesciunt cupiditate incidunt velit, vitae dolorum vero placeat et nihil libero laborum hic, omnis quos officiis, sapiente quam perferendis expedita aspernatur, enim quo modi? Corporis perspiciatis, minus nemo. Iusto maiores culpa est accusantium, eaque sed dolore sunt cumque vel, laborum aliquid debitis excepturi? Dicta ea saepe pariatur molestias rem doloremque, cupiditate totam labore, nostrum sint suscipit quisquam dolores, voluptatem velit. Enim doloribus earum iste, culpa placeat. Eaque esse totam obcaecati libero at maiores dicta, iste dolorem facere nobis mollitia. Ducimus iste commodi ex, in amet enim deleniti minus porro fugit. Dolores ipsam minus atque enim eum reprehenderit quia recusandae vero consectetur, excepturi dolore, doloremque sit.</div>
    <div class="bottom-padding">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="right-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore nisi, neque libero, unde placeat sunt minus modi reiciendis maiores rerum beatae molestiae harum animi magnam, deleniti dignissimos doloribus dolorum mollitia. Corporis aspernatur, delectus alias possimus nostrum, non, debitis ducimus voluptatibus voluptates animi deleniti obcaecati iste. Pariatur aliquid maiores eveniet unde nisi voluptas possimus nostrum totam nulla exercitationem. Quod tempore esse ducimus ratione quas soluta accusamus in, enim, doloremque similique sit laborum corporis veritatis dicta reiciendis debitis praesentium, inventore molestias eius quia officia quibusdam nemo? Omnis, asperiores, corporis. Amet cupiditate doloribus quia nemo modi voluptates, odio, repellendus nesciunt recusandae velit labore iste, quasi suscipit optio, aliquam assumenda vitae illo. Provident nemo incidunt veniam eveniet in est quis numquam, doloribus voluptatem beatae assumenda, non earum expedita qui corporis aliquam vitae. Ratione quos, excepturi laboriosam. Libero, ullam. Fugiat animi debitis quisquam mollitia magnam quos reprehenderit cum, libero dolores voluptate explicabo magni dignissimos nisi, officia. Consequuntur autem sint deserunt veniam aspernatur. Alias explicabo incidunt quas ipsum autem, laboriosam, asperiores quo ad. Impedit, beatae odit maiores, saepe aperiam voluptate reprehenderit quis repellat enim commodi numquam repellendus illo qui quas ipsa molestiae quae! Quis, vitae illum! Eius eaque nemo facere, minima adipisci suscipit ullam, officiis laborum culpa recusandae nisi possimus qui provident sed. Reprehenderit libero, totam sint adipisci similique facere cum, magni expedita obcaecati esse quaerat odio necessitatibus amet. Consectetur fuga neque, deleniti dolorem ad repellendus eius molestiae sequi accusamus voluptas inventore itaque commodi, ipsa enim, dolore ab perferendis asperiores facilis quisquam qui, velit odio eaque! Consectetur porro aperiam, voluptate similique, provident at labore magnam alias incidunt! Ratione sint repellat delectus nihil fuga facilis. Tempora repellendus, quae quibusdam sed dolores laborum, quas. Maiores repudiandae cum consectetur unde, illum cupiditate est. Eum nemo, ut, laborum accusamus animi natus similique nisi facere. Doloremque sed expedita quia harum, praesentium ratione, eaque architecto earum laboriosam repudiandae cum dolore omnis repellendus, error numquam placeat dolores ex. Cupiditate, placeat totam quas doloribus aliquid odit. Voluptate quos libero autem dolorem corporis animi ratione quam laboriosam alias, assumenda natus sunt maxime consectetur officia similique est, sapiente nobis? Distinctio aspernatur dolor maxime dolores non quisquam asperiores corporis fugit sunt aperiam aut vel delectus praesentium voluptatibus ratione inventore, accusantium doloribus minus, corrupti facere exercitationem quaerat consequuntur. Commodi omnis consectetur ad, distinctio accusamus temporibus possimus, eligendi perspiciatis cupiditate, nisi suscipit facere earum aut corporis assumenda. Ratione alias fugiat culpa velit. Similique explicabo impedit reprehenderit officia beatae eum eius, dolor enim officiis distinctio veritatis. Fugiat velit assumenda sequi, quas cupiditate magnam dolores quaerat ullam ad vero. Consequuntur modi, eos repellat? Neque facilis aperiam, sint nisi, obcaecati distinctio dolor accusamus veniam consequatur ab nemo illo sequi quod dicta, ipsa ad nobis, autem ex ut delectus. Fugiat aliquid odio placeat doloremque eos a necessitatibus aliquam non nesciunt, minus maiores ducimus nobis dolorum alias deleniti accusamus libero excepturi dolores consequatur ex odit? Tempore, quas reiciendis fugit. Et a optio saepe, mollitia labore magni necessitatibus minima, aspernatur nostrum iusto, facilis doloremque explicabo! Deserunt optio quas fuga ipsum eveniet, perferendis at quo asperiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias ex aliquam incidunt labore, hic aspernatur minima quis dolorem ab illo modi sunt magni, explicabo repudiandae. In ipsam, deserunt maxime nemo mollitia nihil quis cumque similique accusamus perspiciatis atque laudantium rem illo dolores necessitatibus. Laudantium laborum officiis repellat non delectus error animi quia magni corporis ipsam architecto fuga repudiandae quo doloribus, dolorum cum ea quam ad nobis, dolores eos pariatur magnam atque debitis! Ex excepturi vel non? Voluptatum, esse quos. Perspiciatis architecto blanditiis hic. Dignissimos doloremque veritatis, debitis consequuntur praesentium unde, explicabo eaque nemo officia consequatur cumque tempore. Perspiciatis, fugit, totam.</div>
    <div class="bottom-padding">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "b b" auto
                 "w g" auto
                 "r g" 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 8px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.b {   grid-area: b;   background: blue;                      }
.w {   grid-area: w;   background: white;                     }
.g {   grid-area: g;   background: green;   overflow: auto;   }
.r {   grid-area: r;   background: red;     overflow: auto;   }
```

```html
<div class="b">Top blue line.</div>
<div class="w">White block on the left side.</div>
<div class="g">Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side.</div>
<div class="r">Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side.</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это, я так понял, реализовано через grid css?

Comment: Это - да. В соседнем ответе есть на flex.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ можете объяснить свойство  grid-template? 1 строка это  grid-template-rows  2 строка это grid-template-rows 3 строка это grid-template-areas ?

Comment: @Leks, нет. В кавычках - это areas по строкам, после кавычек - высота строки, после слеша - ширина столбцов.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо в интернете значения этого свойства по разному пишется поэтому непонятно ...

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 8px;
}

.t {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.b {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.w, .g, .r {
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}

.w {   flex: 0 0 auto;   background: white;                                         }
.g {   flex: 1 0 0px;    background: green;   overflow: auto;   margin-top:  8px;   }
.r {   flex: 1 0 100%;   background: red;     overflow: auto;   margin-left: 8px;   }
```

```html
<div class="t">Top blue line.</div>
<div class="b">
  <div class="w">White block on the left side.</div>
  <div class="g">Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side. Green block on the right side.</div>
  <div class="r">Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side. Red block on the left side.</div>
</div>
```